# Need columns stacked as rows for each item in first row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datatable, streamlit

I am sure my issue has to do with how I set up the initial layout of my data, but I am at a loss.

1. I am importing from a csv file.
2. The file has thousands of rows and hundreds of columns.
3. Each row has data on separate companies that runs across the columns.
4. The first few Columns are descriptive and the rest are financial figures.
5. The financial figures span several years (11 to be exact) and I have already ordered them sequentially along the columns (I will give example below).

The end result I want is to create a report for each company and to reorganize the columns into rows.

**Original File looks like this:**

| Symbol | Name | Stock Exchange | RBICS Economy | Sales0 | Sales1 | Sales2 | NetInc0 | NetInc1 | NetInc2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Agilent Technologies, Inc. | NYSE | Healthcare | 6319 | 5339 | 5163 | 438 | 232 | 724 | ... |
| AA | Alcoa Corporation | NYSE | Non-Energy Materials | 12437 | 9372 | 10495 | 429 | -170 | -1125 | ... |
| AABB | Asia Broadband, Inc. | NYSE | Finance | 2.765 | 22.622 | 8.329 | 4.459 | 68.155 | 13.168 | ... |

*Note:the Sales0,Sales1,Sales2,... Represent Sales figures for 2023, 2022, 2021,... The same for every other column item. *

What I want is this:

*(I don't care where the first few descriptive Columns go (i.e. Symbol,Name,Stock Exchange,RBICS Economy).  In fact they could be represented in a separate table.)
*

For each Symbol, present the data in Sales, NetInc,... columns one top of the other:

For symbol, A

| Financial item | 2023 | 2022 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 6319 | 5339 | 5163 |
| NetInc | 438 | 232 | 724 |

For Symbol, AA

| Financial item | 2023 | 2022 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | 12437 | 9372 | 10495 |
| NetInc | 429 | -170 | -1125 |

I might mention I am trying to get the output in streamlit-but I am open to other options.

My best attempt:

```
sales_columns = ['Sales0', 'Sales1', 'Sales2', 'Sales3', 'Sales4', 'Sales5', 'Sales6', 'Sales7', 'Sales8', 'Sales9', 'Sales10', 'Sales11']
net_income_columns = ['NetInc0', 'NetInc1', 'NetInc2', 'NetInc3', 'NetInc4', 'NetInc5', 'NetInc6', 'NetInc7', 'NetInc8', 'NetInc9', 'NetInc10', 'NetInc11']
ebit_columns = ['EBIT0', 'EBIT1', 'EBIT2', 'EBIT3', 'EBIT4', 'EBIT5', 'EBIT6', 'EBIT7', 'EBIT8', 'EBIT9', 'EBIT10', 'EBIT11']
equity_columns = ['Equity0', 'Equity1', 'Equity2', 'Equity3', 'Equity4', 'Equity5', 'Equity6', 'Equity7', 'Equity8', 'Equity9', 'Equity10', 'Equity11']
tangible_assets_columns = ['TangibleAssets0', 'TangibleAssets1', 'TangibleAssets2', 'TangibleAssets3', 'TangibleAssets4', 'TangibleAssets5', 'TangibleAssets6', 'TangibleAssets7', 'TangibleAssets8', 'TangibleAssets9', 'TangibleAssets10', 'TangibleAssets11']

# List of column groups
column_groups = [sales_columns, net_income_columns, ebit_columns, equity_columns, tangible_assets_columns]

# List of years
years = ['2023', '2022', '2021', '2020', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014', '2013']

# List to store DataFrames for each company
result_tables = []

# Iterate over each company
for company in df['Symbol'].unique():
    # Filter the DataFrame for the current company
    company_df = df[df['Symbol'] == company]
    
    # Melt each column group separately
    melted_dfs = []
    for group in column_groups:
        melted_df = pd.melt(company_df, id_vars=['Symbol'], value_vars=group, var_name='Variable', value_name=company)
        melted_dfs.append(melted_df)

    # Concatenate melted DataFrames along columns
    result_table = pd.concat(melted_dfs, axis=1)

    # Add a 'Group Item' column to indicate the column group
    result_table['Group Item'] = result_table['Variable'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])

    # Reorder columns
    result_table = result_table[['Group Item', company] + years]

    # Drop the 'Variable' column
    result_table = result_table.drop(columns='Variable')

    # Append the result to the list
    result_tables.append(result_table)

# Display the resulting tables for each company
for idx, result_table in enumerate(result_tables, 1):
    print(f"\nTable for Company {idx}:\n{result_table}")
```

I get a KeyError: 'Group Item'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
3799     loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
3800 except KeyError:
3801     # This item wasn't present, just insert at end

Comment: Try using `pd.melt`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Could you also paste in your best attempt, so readers can see your current approach?

Comment: Thank you for the update - much better 

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```py
# melt the DataFrame on "Symbol", group by "Symbol" and "Financial item", then sum the values in each group
df = (
    df.melt("Symbol", var_name="Financial item")
    .groupby(["Symbol", "Financial item"])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)

# remove rows that do not have numeric values
df["value"] = pd.to_numeric(df["value"], errors="coerce")
df = df[~df["value"].isna()]

# define a "year" column based on the trailing numbers from "Financial item" values and a dict `years`
years = {0: 2023, 1: 2022, 2: 2021}
df["year"] = (
    df["Financial item"].apply(lambda x: int(re.findall(r"\d+$", x)[-1])).map(years)
)

# remove the trailing numbers from "Financial item" values
df["Financial item"] = df["Financial item"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"\d+$", "", x))

# for each symbol, print the symbol, then pivot the table to have years as columns
for symbol in df["Symbol"].drop_duplicates().to_numpy():
    print("Symbol", symbol)
    symbol_df = df.drop(columns="Symbol").loc[df["Symbol"] == symbol]
    symbol_df = symbol_df.pivot_table(
        index="Financial item", columns="year", values="value"
    ).reset_index()
    symbol_df.columns.name = None
    symbol_df = symbol_df[["Financial item"] + list(years.values())]  # Reorder columns
    print(symbol_df)
```

This will print:

```
Symbol A
  Financial item    2023    2022    2021
0         NetInc   438.0   232.0   724.0
1          Sales  6319.0  5339.0  5163.0
Symbol AA
  Financial item     2023    2022     2021
0         NetInc    429.0  -170.0  -1125.0
1          Sales  12437.0  9372.0  10495.0
Symbol AABB
  Financial item   2023    2022    2021
0         NetInc  4.459  68.155  13.168
1          Sales  2.765  22.622   8.329
```